# Syzygies and their associated varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I want to read about syzygies and their associated varieties and I need some books or articles about this subject.

I found on internet ''The geometry of syzygies'' by David Eisenbud.